# Create a DF following conditions in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a new developper in Spark Scala and I have (I think...) a simple question.
I have a "Client" table like this :

```
ID   City   Timestamp
1         NY        0
1         WDC       10
1         NY        11    
2         NY        20
3         WDC       15
```

And I want to create a second table based on **different conditions on table 1 values**.

For example :

- if ID = 1, I will store the same value than the first table
- if ID = 2, I will store ID, City, Timestamp/2
- if ID = 3, I will store ID, City, 0 as Timestamp.

I am not familiar with Map concepts and I just want to know how is the logic in Spark Scala to do such treatments. Should I create for example 3 DF and at the end do an union between the three Dataframes ?

Can you help me PLEASE with the code (then : I will change the values for the other conditions, but I just want to understand the logic please). For example :

```
var df_input = spark.sql("""select * from clients
""")

val df1 = new (id STRING, city STRING, timestamp STRING);
val df2;
val df3;


if df_input.id === 1 {
df1.id = df_input.id
df1.city = df_input.city
df1.timestamp = df_input.timestamp

} else if df_input.id === 2 {
df2.timestamp = df_input.timestamp / 2
}
var result = df1.union(df2).union(df3)
```

Excuse me for my bad code but I am not really familiar with map concept and Scala. I am more familiar with Java

Comment: you just want to give to the `map` operator a function that does a different thing depending on a certain condition.

Comment: You should have a look to UDFs in org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ package. No need to write scala code in your case

Comment: yeah I understand you but just as I wrote before I just need an example please of what scala code can look like in that case and I will validate your answer. That's all !